# How to find value from list using drool?

Tags: java, list, drools

I am totally new to the Drools, I have a `java.util.list` that contails following value ,

```
 ["abc", "def", "5"]
```

Now i want to check whether the value in third index is greater than 2 or any other number using drool condition. How can i do this?

Comment: how do you plan to compare alphabets with numbers?

Comment: How is this List declared, created and inserted into Working Memory? What do you mean by "2 or any other number"?